# Unitary G-module

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm not sure if I understand this sentence correctly:

"By a unitary G-module we will mean a Hilbert space W on which G acts by means of a strongly continuous unitary representation".

$G$ is a locally compact group.

I know that an action of a group $G$ on $W$ is a map $G\times W\rightarrow W$ and a unitary representation of $G$ is a homomorphism $U: G\rightarrow U(W)$ where $U(W)$ is the set of unitary operators on W. Is "unitary G-module" just another word for "A Hilbert space with a unitary representation of G which is strongly continuous"? I'm not sure about the "on which G acts by means of" part.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch
On the next page for a $C^*$-algebra $A$ a Hermitian $A$-module is defined to be a Hilbert space $W$ on which $A$ acts by means of a continuous non-degenerate *-representation into $L(W)$ (algebra of bounded operators on $W$)
Is it correct that again I can think of a Hermitian $A$-module just as a Hilbert space with a representation of some $C^*$-algebra $A$ on $L(W)$ or as a Hilbert space with an action of $A$ on $W$ which one can read as a linear map from $A$ into $L(W)$ (and satisfies certain conditions)?

Comment: Maybe I am reading this the wrong way, but an action of an algebra $A$ on $W$ is a bilinear map $A \times W \rightarrow W$ with properties analogous to the group case whereas a representation of $A$ on $W$ is an algebra homomorphism $A \rightarrow \text{End}(W)$ (In your last sentence this seems to be mixed up). Like in the group case, these two concepts can be transformed into one another e.g.  if we want the representation of $A$ on $W$ to map inside $L(W)$ the corresponding condition on the action $A \times W \rightarrow W$ would be that the maps $w \mapsto aw$ are bounded operators.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit "Add Comment" and tried to finish before running out of editing time. So I did mix it up a little. What I wanted to say in my last sentence was pretty much what you said in yours. Again: thank you for your help. All questions answered, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

In the following I will try to explain how actions of $G$ and representations of $G$ are related, as I believe this was your main problem here.

An action of $G$ on $W$ is a map $G \times W \rightarrow W, (g,w) \mapsto g.w$ which has the two properties $1.w = w$ and $(gh).w = g.(h.w)$ for all $g,h \in G$ and $w\in W$. Thus the maps $w \mapsto g.w$ are all bijections and from the properties above it follows that
$$ G \rightarrow \text{Sym}(W), g \mapsto (w \mapsto g.w) $$
is a homomrphism of groups (where $\text{Sym}(W)$ denotes the symmetric groups of the set $W$).
Conversely, every homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow \text{Sym}(W)$ defines an action $G \times W \rightarrow W$given by $ g.w = \rho(g)(w)$ for $g \in G$ and $w \in W$.

Now let's say we want the maps $w \mapsto g.w$ not only to be bijections but unitary operators, then from this assumption on the action $G \times W \rightarrow W$, the corresponding homomorphism into the symmetric group has its image in $U(W)$, so in fact we get a homomorphism into $U(W)$, thus a unitary representation $G \rightarrow U(W)$.

So having a unitary representation $G \rightarrow U(W)$ is equivalent to having an action $G \times W \rightarrow W$ with $w \mapsto g.w$ being unitary for all $g$.

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped a lot.